# Bare bones web form example using python3 & mod_wsgi (no Django)?

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have an apache + mod_wsgi + python3.1 setup. (Plain, no Django or other framework.) I can write apps that output HTML, but I can't seem to get a basic web form + POST parser to work so I can also handle input. I've found some examples online that are several years old and use python2, and several pages describing the "issues you should be aware of" with python3 that make the python2 examples obsolete (long list of encoding issues new to python3, etc.)

Would anyone happen to have python3 code ("def application(environ, start_response):...") that puts up a small UTF-8 web form with a couple of short menus that, when you submit (POST) it, puts those UTF-8 menu choices into python3 strings? A python3 script that handles the issues properly regarding telling it the right number of bytes to read from the request, doesn't munge the UTF-8 for non-ASCII chars, doesn't use deprecated functions, etc., that can be used as a bare-bones template by people trying to use mod_wsgi + python3 for input as well as output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

def application(environ, start_response):
    try:
        path = environ['PATH_INFO']
    except KeyError:
        path = environ['REQUEST_URI'].decode('utf-8').split('=', 1)[1]
    method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
    get = dict(parse_qsl(environ['QUERY_STRING'], keep_blank_values=True))
    post = dict(parse_qsl(environ['wsgi.input'].read().decode('utf-8')))

    if path == '/my_form':
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
        yield '''\
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name">What is your name?</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>'''.encode('utf-8')
        if method == 'POST' and 'name' in post:
            yield "<p>Hello, {}!</p>".format(post['name']).encode('utf-8')
    else:
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        yield "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>".encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, BlaXpirit. It took a while for me to figure out what to edit to get this to work (I couldn't use the name of my form in "if path =='/my_form'", but had to set it to "if path==''"), but it now works. Now that I have a working starting point I can experiment with variations.

Comment: @Glen I used a local CherryPy server to test this, your server probably does something different with the `environ`. You should log it: `yield str(environ).encode('utf-8')`, mess with the address line of the browser (don't forget to remove the `if path==...`!) and see what changes there and is suitable to obtain the path.

Comment: Just a comment: Python is a wildly popular language these days. Apache is the #1 server. The current and future python is python3, and the current and future standard for python on apache is mod_wsgi. So how can it be that it's easier to find example code for building a whole web server in *emacs lisp*, for heaven's sake, than a simple "hello, world" web form in python3? Why is this of so little interest? Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about python web apps that makes the question of how to write a simple "hello, world" on apache strangely exotic or utterly irrelevant?

Comment: @Glen People don't use Python 3 with web because there's no Django for Python 3. Django isn't ported because Python 3 does have problems with WSGI. Those problems aren't being fixed so fast because people don't use Python 3 for web. That's my thoughts. But Armin Ronacher's [**thoughts**](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/12/7/thoughts-on-python3/) are probably more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want any frameworks, but I encourage you to try [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/). It doesn't require any installation, you can just put the *bottle.py* file into your project folder and you're ready to go.
And yes, it works with Python 3!

```py
import bottle
from bottle import get, post, request

@get('/my_form')
def show_form():
    return '''\
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name">What is your name?</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>'''

@post('/my_form')
def show_name():
    return "Hello, {}!".format(request.POST.name)

application=bottle.default_app()       # run in a WSGI server
#bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080) # run in a local test server
```

Comment: You're right that I don't want a framework. I'm probably not the only one who would like to see the basic skeleton of a working python3 web form in mod_wsgi. But I am grateful for your answer, because after learning how to do it manually, I'll want to understand my other options, too.